# Find the maximum of $f(x, y) = (3x+4y)e^{\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2}}$ as a function of $r$ over a closed disk $x^2+y^2\leq r^2.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the maximum of $f(x, y) = (3x+4y)e^{\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2}}$ as a function of $r$ over a closed disk $x^2+y^2\leq r^2.$

So my first guess is to check the interior points and then the boundry points. But, how do I get the function $f$ as a function of $r$?

I rewrote it as following, but not sure if this is right.

$$f(x(r, t), y(r, t)) = (3r\cos{t}+4r\sin{t})e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}},$$

I can then get the parital derivatites:

$$f_r=(3\cos{t}+4\sin{t})e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} - (3r^2\cos{t}+4r^2\sin{t})e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}$$
$$f_t=(-3r\sin{t}+4r\cos{t})e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}$$

Then, I can find when the derivatives are equal to $0$,

$$f_t=(-3r\sin{t}+4r\cos{t})e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} = 0 \implies \tan{t} = \frac{4}{3}.$$

I think I'm doing this totally wrong. Maybe I should use Lagrange multipliers somehow?

Answer is: $max(r) = 5re^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}$ if $r \leq 1$ and $max(r) =\frac{5}{\sqrt{e}}$ if $r \geq 1$. $min(r) = -max(r)$.

Comment: No, you're not doing it totally wrong. Keep going. Put in the value of t that you've found and find the maximum with respect to r.

Comment: You have good ideas, but one important misstep. It is quite natural trying to apply polar coordinates and go from $(x,y)$ to $(r,t)$. But please note that $r$ is already being defined in the problem as the radius of the disk over which the maximum has to be found, so you can't use it to mean the distance from the origin in polar coordinates.

Comment: @Micheal Behrend Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @Ingix You're totally right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two r's in the problem.  So lets call one something different by saying $x^2+y^2=r^2\le R^2$.

You have correctly calculated $t$ which results in a maximum. This gives $\cos(t)=\frac{4}{5}$ and $\sin(t)=\frac{3}{5}$. Put this into your expression for $f_r$ and it is easy to see that $r=1$.

Now if $R>1$ then you have a maximum at $r=1$ and thus $max[f(x,y)]=5 e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

If $R<1$ then maximum is at $r=R$ so $max[f(x,y)]=5 R e^{-\frac{R^2}{2}}$.

You of course still need to check these are maximums.

Comment: How did you get $\cos{t}=\frac{4}{5}$ and $\sin{t}=\frac{3}{5}$ from the fact that $\tan{t}=\frac{4}{3}$?

Comment: 3-4-5 right angle triangle.

Comment: Ah, yes. I think I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let us see what happens in $D_r(0)$. We have$$f_x(x,y)=e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}2}(-3x^2-4xy+3)\text{ and }f_y(x,y)=e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}2}(-3xy-4y^2+4).$$Therefore, the critical points are the solutions of the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-3x^2-4xy+3=0\\-3xy-4y^2+4=0.\end{array}\right.$$This system has two solutions: $\pm\left(\frac35,\frac45\right)$, which belong to $D_r(0)$ if and only if $r>1$. On the other hand,$$f\left(\pm\left(\frac35,\frac45\right)\right)=\pm\frac5{\sqrt e}.$$

Now, if $x^2+y^2=r^2$, we have $f(x,y)=(3x+4y)e^{-\frac{r^2}2}$. So, if $(x,y)=r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$,\begin{align}f(x,y)&=(3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta)e^{-\frac{r^2}2}\\&=5\left(\frac35\cos\theta+\frac45\sin\theta\right)e^{-\frac{r^2}2}.\end{align}So, the maximum of $f$ in that circle is $5e^{-\frac{r^2}2}$, whereas the minimum is $-5e^{-\frac{r^2}2}$.

Therefore,$$\max f=\begin{cases}\frac5{\sqrt e}&\text{ if }r\geqslant1\\\frac5{e^{\frac{r^2}2}}&\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}\text{ and }\min f=\begin{cases}-\frac5{\sqrt e}&\text{ if }r\geqslant1\\-\frac5{e^{\frac{r^2}2}}&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I also tried it this way, but I couldn't solve the system of equations you described above. How did you get the answer $(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5})$?

Comment: @wednesdaymiko Adding the first equation times $-3$ to second equation times $4$, leads to $16y^2=7+9x^2$. In other words, $y=\pm\sqrt{7+9x^2}$. Now, replace $y$ by this expression in the first equation.

Answer (score 0):

You got

$f(r,t)=$
$(3\cos t +4\sin t)r\exp(-r^2/2)$,
$0\le t \lt 2π, 0<r\le 1.$

The problem is separable :

Find the maxima of

1)$g(t):= 3\cos t +4\sin t$, $0\le t \lt 2π$.

2) $h(r):=r\exp (-r^2/2), 0<r \le 1$.

1) $g(t)= (3,4)(\cos t, \sin t)$ 
(scalar product).

Note $(\cos t, \sin t)$ is a unit vector.

Hence:

$g(t)= |(3,4)||1|\cos \phi$, where $\phi$ is the angle between the vectors.

Hence

max $ (g(t))= \sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$.
$( \cos \phi =1$, i.e. $(3,4)$ and $(\cos t, \sin t)$ are parallel)

2) $h(r)=r\exp(-r^2/2)$.

$h'(r)=$
$ \exp(-r^2/2) +r(-r)\exp(-r^2/2)$;

$h'(r) >0$ for $0<r \lt 1$, i.e strictly increasing $h$.

$h'(r=1)=0$

$h'(r) < 0$ for $r > 1$ , i.e. strictly decreasing $h$.

For $r <1$ : $\max (h(r)) =r\exp(-r^2/2)$.

For $r \ge 1$:  $\max (h(r))= \exp(-1/2)$.

Finally:

$\max (f(r,t)=$
$ (\max (g(t))) (\max (h(r)))$.